# is it possible to create object record based on unrelated object record trough triggers?

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, approval-process

i have a requirement like creating object B's record based on field update on Object A's record. If not, is there any other options to do that.

Comment: You don't need a trigger do to this..

Comment: you can achieve this using process builder instead of writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it would look something like this:

```
trigger ObjectATrigger on ObjectA__c (after update) {
    List<ObjectB__c> objBList = new List<ObjectB__c>();

    for(ObjectA__c objA : trigger.new) {
        // Check criteria to create the ObjectB__c records
        if(....) {
            // Create your ObjectB__c record
            ObjectB__c objB = new ObjectB__c(
                Field1__c = 'value',
                Field2__c = 'value',
                ....
            );
            objBList.add(objB);
        }
    }

    // Insert your ObjectB__c records
    insert objBList;
}
```

As others mentioned, there are other methods to insert records without using code. But the above example should point you in the right direction if you really want to do it in a trigger.

Comment: so it is possible to create unrelated records using trigger... Thanks @Bob i will try it.